# OnClick JS like event

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio, and I don't know why is this code not working.

```
GridLayout divNum1 = findViewById(R.id.DivNum1);
divNum1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    showItemPage(v);
  }
});
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? This sets a click listener on the entire GridLayout. If you want to do something when clicking on a cell in the GridLayout then you will need to set it on the child.

Answer (score 0):

You must add click feature to the layouts. You can try this.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</GridLayout>
```